# Expression Blend 2013 too slow

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, visual-studio-2013, expression-blend

I want to upgrade my project from VS 2010 to 2013 and .NET 4.5.1.

It is a desktop application with many WPF forms (over 200) and I have a big problem with Expression Blend 2013 performance.

It is impossible to work because it constantly freezes (especially when I first open it, at least 10') and has a very slow response time to anything I do (like click on the xaml panel).

My computer specifications are: 
CPU: i7 
RAM: 6 GB
Grafics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti
Operating System: Windows 7 Professional

Does anyone had simillar problems, or has any suggestion?

Comment: I truly wish I didn't have to say this, but 6gb of RAM won't cut it when you start delving into the graphics intensive like the Blend designer. However the rest of it, I mean I have 16gb in the dev machine the company gave me, Blend does good once it's loaded, but the loading of the solution (which for me is over 100+ projects and hundreds of views/resources etc.) takes seemingly forever. Wish I had a better outlook for you, but if you're the designer on your team, you already have the case for needing a better machine to argue to your manager.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the same boat, I ended up upgrading only to realize I am wasting 80% of time waiting on my blend to load/reload my solution I have about 26 projects in 1 solution and about 300-400 views/user controls.

I am used to working simultaneously between Visual studio, and blend View/ViewModel and as soon as I do something or even a simple task of adding a Value Converter, the solution takes 20-30 mins to reload.

Worse I am on TFS so blend takes it own sweet time doing nothing but loading and reloading.

I have 2 installer projects in that solution and it always gets struck with that even after I selected don't show.

AMD FX 8 Core @ 4GHz 
4 GB Graphic card
16GB RAM 
64 Bit Windows 8.1 Pro

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when upgrading my project, the solution for me was to create a new visual studio solution containing only the project that contained the wpf controls, it looks like Blend is slow with big solutions that contain many projects